# Существует ли формат файла, который позволяет сжимать изображение без "деформаций"\потери качества?

Tags: изображения, формат, сжатие

Здравствуйте! 
С этим делом не знаком. Поискал в сети, не нашел.

Существует ли такой формат изображения?
PNG, Jpg вроде как искажают картинку...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PNG, GIF, PCX, BMP RLE, TIFF LZW. Это то, что вспомнилось "навскидку". У каждого свои достоинства и недостатки. Многое зависит от специфики изображений.

Comment: Специфика такая: максимально сжать и не искажать.

Comment: Это специфика процесса. Я ее уже уяснил. А какова специфика изображений? Это фотографии, чертежи, текстуры, скриншоты? Какова максимальная глубина цвета?

Comment: Это фотография, растровая картинка. Глубина цвета 24 бита, альфы нет.

Comment: раз это фотография, тогда gif не подойдет. оптимально png. Хотя jpeg  в данном случае самое оно, главное подобрать правильные параметры сжатия.

Comment: Да, тогда только png с максимальным сжатием. Многие программы позволяют указать глубину сжатия. Например, в XnView по умолчанию 6, но можно выставить 9. Время сжатия при этом намного возрастает, а размер файла получается чуть-чуть меньше.
Кроме того, существуют специальные программы для утрамбовывания PNG. Они работают еще дольше, а выгода еще меньше. Но если каждый байт на счету... Гугли png optimizer.

Answer (score 3):

Новый гугловский [WEBP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/?csw=1) и старый малоизвестный [JPEG 2000](http://www.jpeg.org/jpeg2000/) (.jp2) поддерживают компрессию как с потерями, так и без. То же относится к уже упомянутым [[@VadimTukaev](/users/18204/vadimtukaev)](/users/18204/vadimtukaev) tiff и gif.